# Twig template: Add html in JOIN function

Tags: arrays, templates, join, symfony, twig

I can get all tags related to a post using:

```
{{ post.tags | join(', ') }}
```

It would show:

```
tag1, tag2, tag3, etc
```

How could I get these tags to be a link, not just text?
I mean:

```
<a href="tag1.php">tag1</a>, <a href="tag2.php">tag2</a>, <a href="tag3.php">tag3</a>, etc
```

Am I forced to use foreach(), show tags individually, and add a comma manually?

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes do as Carlos says and check for the last entry so you dont have a lonley comma at the end like:
*tag1, tag2,*

```
{% for tag in post.tags %}
    <a href="{{tag}}.php">{{tag}}</a>{% if loop.last == false %},{% endif %} 
{% endfor %}
```

this would render:
*tag1, tag2*
just as join would.

Comment: Yeah, lonely comma at the end, oldest problem in the world :-)

Answer (score 3):

Do it manually, it is not complicated

```
{% for tag in post.tags %}
    <a href="{{tag}}.php">{{tag}}</a>,
{% endfor %}
```